# NestJS: any way to create a provider for either a web-aware service, or a non web-aware service depending on context

Tags: nestjs

**Background**

I'm working on a large application that needs to be upgraded. If I were starting from scratch I'd do this all differently. But right now I need to figure out a fix without touching hundreds of files.

For the same reason, I ideally need this code to work on Nest 6. This project needs to be upgraded to the latest nest, but there are some things that need to be fixed to do this. Before I can do that, I need to resolve the current issue, which is blocking us from upgrading off of node 12

**Problem**

I have a logger class. This class is supposed to pull in some information from the `REQUEST` context, if one is available (basically, some headers). If no request context is available, this can be ignored.

For simplicity in talking about this, we can say that I need a provider `Logger` which returns either a `RequestAwareLogger` or `PlainLogger` instance, depending on whether or not it is being resolved from a request scope. Alternately, I need the provider to return the same class, with either a `request` injected (via `@Inject(REQUEST)`), or left undefined.

Edit For posterity: If I were writing this from scratch, I'd just update the `logger.log` call to consume this information directly by passing in the request object, or the fields I needed tracked. But since this is a huge project already, I'd have to modify 1000 lines of code in different files, many of which don't have direct access to the request. This will be a longer term effort

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in way to do this in Nest. However, it is possible to create a custom provider that would achieve the same effect.

Here is an example provider that would return either a RequestAwareLogger or PlainLogger instance, depending on whether or not it is being resolved from a request scope:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoggerProvider {
  constructor(
    @Optional() @Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request?: Request,
  ) {}

  getLogger(): PlainLogger | RequestAwareLogger {
    // If a request is available, return a RequestAwareLogger instance
    if (this.request) {
      return new RequestAwareLogger(this.request);
    }
    // Otherwise, return a PlainLogger instance
    return new PlainLogger();
  }
}
```

Then, you can use this provider in your logger service like so:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoggerService {
  constructor(private readonly loggerProvider: LoggerProvider) {}

  log(message: string) {
    const logger = this.loggerProvider.getLogger();
    // Use the logger instance
    logger.log(message);
  }
}
```

Note that this provider will only work if Nest's IoC container is used to resolve the logger service. If you are using a different IoC container (e.g. in a non-Nest application), you will need to create a custom provider for that container.

Comment: Isn't this still implicitly request scoped? Even though the `REQUEST` provider is optional, I believe Nest will still make the `LoggerProvider` scoped to the  `REQUEST` (as it _technically_ exists as a provider in all contexts, just doesn't always exist as a value) and therefore can cause issues in things like websocket gateways and cron job processors

Comment: Didn't think about that. That's definitely a possibility.